# SQL - Mismo registro fecha mas actualizada permitiendo repetición

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, impala

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta que me recupere de la base de datos los usuarios con fecha mas actual y con estado = 1.
El detalle está en que el usuario puede existir muchas veces ya que puede tener distintos perfiles y con estado a 1.
En caso de que el usuario sea insertado con perfil a 0 al tener una fecha mas actualizada que el mismo usuario y con el mismo perfil la consulta no debería traerlo.
En definitiva, traer todos los valores que estén con el estado = 1 basandose en la última fecha de inserción independientemente de los registros que tenga la columna usuario, ya que si el usuario aparece 5 veces con distintos roles debe mostrar los cinco.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imagen mostrada es una consulta de la tabla principal y con la consulta buscada no tendría que traerse  el usuario 0049DWHTEST ya que los registros actualizados son con estado a 0. Pero debería recuperar dos veces al usuario 0049DWHTESTFINAL ya que tiene dos inserciones con hora 14:58:28 y 12:14:47

La consulta con la que estoy probando es la siguiente:

``` SELECT usuario, perfil, estado, ``timestamp`` FROM(SELECT usuario,perfil,estado,``timestamp``, RANK() over (partition by usuario ORDER BY ``timestamp`` DESC) cuenta FROM bu_seguridadsailpoint.SP_MSTR_DWC) dwh WHERE dwh.cuenta = 1 AND estado = 1 ORDER BY UPPER(usuario) DESC ```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Podrias mostrar cual es la salida que vos queres basada en esos datos? esto no es un simple group by?

Comment: Necesito que me muestre los usuarios y perfil que hay cargados sin importar que se repitan ya que no estamos considerando "usuario" como  identificador único con el estado en 1. Pero que si a uno de esos usuarios y perfil se le realiza una carga con el estado a 0, no vuelva a mostrar a ese usuario con ese perfil pero sí, si sigue existiendo con otros. Esto es debido a que sobre la BBDD que estamos trabajando no admite (UPDATE,DELETE) solo trabaja con INSERT. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: podrias mostrar cual es la salida en base a los datos que mostras?